# Do you need to be a member of a gang to be called a gangster and accused of gangsterism?

Tags: expressions, common-word, urban

**Collins**

I understand that the Collins dictionary defines gangsterism to be a person using the methods and behaviour of gangsters, and the tactics associated with gangsters. But it is my current understanding that you do not actually have to be a member of a gang to use the methods, tactics and behaviours associated with gang members, and thus be commonly referred to as a gangster that commits gangsterism.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gangsterism)

> the methods or behavior of gangsters
> 2. the use of tactics associated with gangsters, as intimidation or violence, in order to achieve something

**Urban dictionary**

Certainly, the Urban dictionary which mostly describes the common usage would appear to define gangsterism as simply "acting" like a gangster. Again, I understand this to mean that you do not have to be a member of a gang to be regarded as a gangster.

[Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gangsterism)

> Subscribing to a course of action reminiscent of organized crime. Acting or conducting business in a way that is violent and totally without conscience. Acting like a gangster/thug/hoodlum.

**Wikipedia**

Wikipedia describes a gangster as invariably describing a criminal, and also points out that there is no clear consensus about what constitutes a gang. So here again, I read from this that you do not have to be a member of a gang to be regarded as a gangster.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gangster#Usage)

> In modern usage, the term "gang" is generally used for a criminal organization and the term "gangster" invariably describes a criminal.[2](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gangsterism) Much has been written on the subject of gangs, although there is no clear consensus about what constitutes a gang or what situations lead to gang formation and evolution.

**Merriam Webster**

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/gangster)
According to the Merriam Webster dictionary, a synonym of gangster simply describes a violent and brutal person.

> a violent, brutal person who is often a member of an organized gang

Question

My understanding is that going by the modern and common usage of the word, you do not require to be a member of a gang to be called a gangster. I could however be totally wrong in my thinking and understanding, so therefore I will ask the question, do you need to be a member of a gang to be described as a gangster and accused of gangsterism?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gangsterism) does not have a separate entry but directs to **gangster** : a member of a gang of criminals. I cannot quite see how you can propose that gangsters and gangsterism do not actually involve a gang.

Comment: *Do you need to be a member of a gang to be described as a gangster and accused of gangsterism?* No. People use "gangster" to mean "someone who behaves like a gangster". -- Gangsterism is a different matter: it should usually imply that others conspired with you and these are seen as your "gang" - although this might be figurative rather than actual.

Comment: @Weather Vane. Yet you need to ignore the synonym from the same dictionary, which simply describes a violent, brutal person who is often a member of an organized gang.https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/gangster

Comment: I think the general idea is that brutal criminals rarely work alone, so there's almost always a gang.

Comment: It should be noted that the term "gang" may be applied to a group of friends.  It does not necessarily imply malicious behavior.

Comment: You don't need to be a gangster in any sense to be accused of being one. People do lie.

Comment: The question asks about the normal usage, but a lot of people are replying to say "there are other usages" without regard to how common they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of "gangster" from *Collins* that you yourself cite, "gangsterism" is "the methods or behavior of gangsters" and/or "the use of tactics associated with gangsters, as intimidation or violence, in order to achieve something."

One does not need to actually be a member of a particular thing to employ its *methods or behavior* and/or *use tactics associated* with people who actually are members. If, for example, someone calls me a "fascist," describes me as "fascist," or accuses me of "fascism," their doing so does not necessarily carry the meaning that I'm a member of a fascist party. It could, but not necessarily. It very well may not.

So, the answser to your question is: no, you don't need to be.

*Never mind that to be ***described*** a certain way, ***called*** a certain name, or ***accused*** of a certain thing, you don't ***need to be*** that way, name, or thing since people can be mistaken and since people can lie.*

Comment: The question asks about "the modern and common usage of the word". Is your answer about that, or about alternative, more unusual usages?

Comment: In answer to your question, no, my answer's not about alternative, more unusual usages because, as you suggest in your comment, that wouldn't be an answer to the OP's question. Also, the *Collins* definition cited by the OP would stipulate the definition as being *rare*, if unusual, or *archaic*, if not modern. Without such stipulations, it goes without saying that the definition supplied is current, or "modern" as you put it, and in common usage, just like it goes without saying in my answer to the OP's question since that's expressly what the OP's question is about.

Comment: Now, I had considered adding something about "gangsta," how it's a modern slang derivation of "gangster," "gangsta" at times meaning the same thing as "gangster" and at other times nuance in definition or effect or both. I ultimately refrained because of it being extraneous to the answer of the OP's question as stated. I only bring it up here, though, because the usages of "gangsta," particular those that are identical to "gangster," underscore my answer to your question in your comment that my answer to the OP's question *is* about modern or common usage, which otherwise goes without saying.